# ls working strangely

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint, autocomplete, ls

I'm used to typing `ls Doc`, and tabbing a couple times to complete to `ls Documents/`.

However, now my ls is completing that same statement to `ls Documents` with a space at the end of Documents, so I can use it to find my way through the file tree.

This started happening today. Any ideas why and more importantly, *how to fix*?

**Edit**

This happens for ANY and ALL directories. Documents was an example. `$CDPATH` is empty.

`complete | grep ls` returns `complete -o default -F _longopt ls` as the only relevant answer.

`locate Documents` turns up stuff in /usr/lib/

Comment: Is there a file in the current directory (where you are trying to perform the complete from) named "Documents"?  Does it act the same way in/for other directories?

Comment: Yes, it behaves uniformly in every folder. Documents is a folder, there are no similarly named files. This also isn't a result of a .bashrc causing issues. I've made no changes to it, and moved it out of the way temporarily but that hasn't helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple things that may be happening.

1) do `complete | grep ls` and see if there are any special completions for ls. There may be code that is changing what you expect completion to do

2) do `echo $CDPATH` This variable is a list of special directories that bash will look for, outside of the local directory, for `cd`. I'm not sure if ls uses this, but worth a try.

You can also try `locate Documents` and see if you find a directory that it may be trying to reference.

**EDIT**

It looks like you're using the bash_completion package. It tries to run the function _longopt when you ask for completion. Try `complete -f ls` and see if `ls` now behaves as you expect.

Comment: Attempted all of these. I'm not sure what I should expect from `complete`'s output and have edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you so much. This solved it. Now to figure out where that setting got changed.

Comment: @EricR look for the bash_completion package, you may have that installed. Check out /etc/profile and /etc/profile.d

Comment: I'm writing this for future reference. I ended up finding a line in /etc/bash_completion which specified `-F _longopt` which I changed to read `-f` which solves my problem completely

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, the only scenario that makes sense is that some time in the past Documents was a symlink that pointed to some directory, and today Documents is still a symlink but pointing to one of the following:

1. something that is not a directory.
2. something that no longer exists.
3. something that you can't access enough to determine if it is a directory or not.