# ls *.pdf complains: ls: invalid option -- '_'

Tags: debian, coreutils

I'm used to using 'ls' as I would in Linux Mint, e.g. 'ls *.pdf', but in this Debian variant 'ls *.pdf' complains. I find myself using a length 'find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.pdf" -print' instead.

Reading this: [ls working strangely](https://superuser.com/questions/392535/ls-working-strangely) did not help too much. I do have bash_completions package and I have no weird aliases for 'ls' in my '~/.bashrc' file - I never edit the '/etc/profile' or the global one, wherever it is.

Just guessing, I did apply the solution in the linked question but it didn't work. I don't fully understand 'complete' - I guess it is part of 'readline' - so maybe a short explanation would help too (It has no 'man' page).

This works though: 'complete -p ls *.pdf', which 'complete --help' says,

```
 -p        print existing completion specifications in a reusable format
```

and so I wonder if I should permanently apply this 'rule'? using the '-D' flag...?

**EDIT**

Just noticed this problem too:

```
for f in *.pdf; do mv "$f" "BOOK - $F"; done

mv: invalid option -- 'R'
```

**EDIT 2**

I tried the two commands above and they work fine - on my OS's partition. The problems are when I move to a different partition, with the working Linux Mint on it and the pdf files I want to modify, that these commands fail. Both partitions are ext4, both have the same username, hostname, UID/GID, permissions, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have filenames with leading dash `-`, so use :

```
for f in *.pdf; do mv -- "$f" "BOOK - $F"; done
```

From `man bash` :

> A `--` signals the end of options and disables further option processing.  Any arguments after the -- are treated as  file‐
>   names and arguments.  An argument of - is equivalent to --.

Comment: Is that some sort of Bash magic? I don't see it in the man page for mv...

Comment: It's not specific for mv but for shell, it means _end of options_

Comment: @nate, see [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html) for more info. TL;DR: this is a convention put forward by GNU libc (the standard C library typically used on Linux-based systems) and the core/file utilities written with its help. The convention sort of stuck (for good).

Comment: I'd also explain *why* the observed behaviour happens. Unix shells (contrary to those of Windows) expand "wildcards" by themselves; that is, when you run `some_command *.pdf` in your shell, the shell sees that `*.pdf` and tries to match the set of files in its current directory; if that happens, the `some_command` will be passed *several distinct* arguments—each being the name of a single file that matched. If the matching fails (no files found) the argument will be passed as is—`*.pdf`.

Comment: …As a corollary, you could even have files named `--`, `-a` and `-b`, and call `some_command -*` with some interesting (and unpredictable, from run to run) results ;-) What I'm leading to, is the for production code you'll almost always want `find $dir -type f -name '*.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 some_command`

Answer (score 1):

If you have filenames that start with `-` (minus or hyphen), many programs interpret them as options.

You can prepend `./` to the path to avoid it:

```
ls ./*.pdf
```

Many programs also allow inserting `--` before filename arguments to signal end of options:

```
ls -- *.pdf
```

The recommended approach for users is of course to rename the files.

Comment: Oh, I see. So just a simple file name starting with a dash caused these errors. I did find one and renamed it and now it works.